# Creating installer for a C# Windows forms app with MS Access dependency

Tags: c#, ms-access, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have a C# Windows Forms app that uses OleDB and Office Interop to create and modify an MS Access file on the system. I'm trying to use Microsoft's official installer extension to make an installer for my app.

The installer gets built successfully and installs. But the problem is when trying to access those two files, I get an error

> Could not load file or assembly

I want to be able to install those dependencies when installing the program so these issues won't occur.

Comment: Please refer to [C# Custom Operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/d9k65z2d(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). You can follow the link to get the new installer project referenced from the installer solution. You need to do it this way so that you can build the dll that is called at the end of the installation.